# Iterate through all the elements of json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax call, in the success I am getting json object of the following format:

```
{test 1: Array(2), test 2: Array(3), test 3: Array(2)}
```

The arrays inside each key looks like

```
0: {IdProduct: "1", ProductName: "p1", ProductCode: "pc1", ProductVersion: "pv1"}
1: {IdProduct: "2", ProductName: "p2", ProductCode: "pc2", ProductVersion: "pv2"}
```

I want to iterate through all these elements to create a option group 
My understanding is to have two for loops and create levels in first loop nd options in second loop, I have written the following code which is not working fine:

```
    success: function(response) {
                    var options = '<optgroup label="'+Object.keys(response)[0]+'">';
                    response.forEach(function (data) {
                        options += '<option value="' + data.IdProduct + '">' + data.ProductName;
                        options += '</option>';
                    });
 options += '</optgroup>';
                    productsFilter.html(options);
                }
```

Comment: Since your response is a json object, when you do for loop, it takes the json's key as element, hence to access your array inside, you need to do like "response[data].IdProduct"...

Comment: How to create the first for loop to access test1, test2 etc? all these elements are not in array, please check once the format in the post

Comment: @JayBlanchard How are those PHP posts related to this JavaScript post?

Comment: @srikantamondal Just do a for loop to go through the json's keys then another loop for its element if it's an array, check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cr8Lj65q/

Comment: Can you show the exact output you're looking to receive/create?

Comment: @Teemu prior to an edit the OP had tagged with PHP. Honestly, there are probably as many JS dupes for this question too.

Answer (score 0):

You do need two loops to do this.  I did a for-in to iterate through the top JSON properties and then did used your foreach for the arrays.  By the way, I mocked up the JSON response just to fill in the rest.

```js
var response = {
  'test 1': [{
    IdProduct: "1", 
    ProductName: "p1", 
    ProductCode: "pc1", 
    ProductVersion: "pv1"
  },{
    IdProduct: "2", 
    ProductName: "p2", 
    ProductCode: "pc2", 
    ProductVersion: "pv2"
  }], 
  'test 2': [{
    IdProduct: "3", 
    ProductName: "p3", 
    ProductCode: "pc3", 
    ProductVersion: "pv3"
  },{
    IdProduct: "4", 
    ProductName: "p4", 
    ProductCode: "pc4", 
    ProductVersion: "pv4"
  },{
    IdProduct: "5", 
    ProductName: "p5", 
    ProductCode: "pc5", 
    ProductVersion: "pv5"
  }], 
  'test 3': [{
    IdProduct: "6", 
    ProductName: "p6", 
    ProductCode: "pc6", 
    ProductVersion: "pv6"
  },{
    IdProduct: "7", 
    ProductName: "p7", 
    ProductCode: "pc7", 
    ProductVersion: "pv7"
  }]};

var options = "";
for (var key in response) {  
  options += '<optgroup label="'+ key + '">';
  response[key].forEach(function (data) {
    options += '<option value="' + data.IdProduct + '">' + data.ProductName;
    options += '</option>';
  });
  options += '</optgroup>';
}

var productsFilter = $("select#productsFilter");
productsFilter.html(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="productsFilter"></select>
```